# Unable to start mysql

Tags: linux, mysql-5.1

I am using Oracle LINUX5. I installed MySQL 5.1.73 community edition through RPM command and it was working. Now, I stop mysql by running below command:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -ptmpassword shutdown
```

I did not get any message after executing the above command. When I run below command to start the service:

```
$ /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql start
```

I got below message:
**Starting MySQL.Manager of pid-file quit without updating fi[FAILED]**

Now, I am unable to connect MySQL database.

- How can I start MySQL again?
- What is the reason behind not starting the service?

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer and I want to laugh on myself... What a silly mistake I did!
Sharing this solution so that others can save their time.
I just prefix **sudo** command in the below statement and mysql started.

```
$ sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql start
```

Input password:
Starting MySQL.
I checked and found that MySQL is running by issuing below command:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -pjoomla1 ping
```

**mysqld is alive**